# How do I pass parameters to a crystal report, 2 of which are not actually used?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a free-form SQL query which I'd like to use in the report.  I want to pass one report parameter but I also have 2 other parameters I'd like to pass in, but are actually unused.  The reason for adding them is because the report generator code is used by other legacy systems and those reports require those 2 parameters.

Currently it seems that if the parameters are unused in the query they are removed from the parameter list.  So instead I thought I might try adding the parameters into the select to make sure they are used, but this causes a syntax error.

e.g.

```
select o.*, {?param2}, {?param3} from orders as o where o.orderid = {?OrderqId}
```

Excuse my limited knowledge of Crystal. How do I get round this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `param2` and `param3` are strings, try:

```
SELECT  O.*, '{?param2}' PARAM2, '{?param3}' PARAM3
FROM    ORDERS O
WHERE   O.ORDERID = {?OrderqId}
```